PHP SQL Server Connection on IIS
I am not able to connect SQL server with PHP. whenever I try to connect, it says..

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\resolute\php\connection.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\resolute\php\connection.php on line 7

but php.info works fine...
tried PHP version 8.3 / 8.2 / 8.1 but all failed
I've installed proper drive in ext folder and also enabled the required extension for the drivers. Still problem persists. any help?
here's my code
<?php
$serverName = "192.168.0.101, 5566"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"DBname", "UID"=>"myuser", "PWD"=>"smypwd");
$connectionInfo = [
    'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8',
];
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === True) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>


You haven't enabled the sqlsrv extension in your php.ini.

Use this search [php] undefined function sqlsrv_connect answers:1 to find similar questions. There may be various underlying causes, so it's hard to know which one will be your solution.

Does this error only occur on IIS? Do you get this error when running locally?

Thanks a lot. It worked. It was a driver version issue.
